# How to change the proxy settings for the Network Service account from the command prompt?

Tags: windows, proxy, command-line-interface

Currently, I am only aware of the following command:

```
C:\>bitsadmin /util /SetIEProxy NetworkService MANUAL_PROXY 1 92.168.0.200:8080 NULL
```

But, it has the following defects:

- It is deprecated
- It does not allow to set the credentials.

My question is how can I configure the proxy settings, including the credentials using a more up-to-date tool?

**EDIT**

I would like to stress that I am looking for a command line utility to do that.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: I have Windows 7, but ultimately I am interested in all the versions from XP up.

Comment: "Administrative tools for the BITS service are now provided by BITS PowerShell cmdlets."  Might be worth investigating.

Answer (score -1):

With the built-in Group Policy mechanism: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy

Comment: I want a command line tool to perform a certain task. I know of a tool which satisfies the demand only partially and I wish to know if a better tool exists. I am sorry, but I do not see how your reply answers my question.

Comment: Yes, I do - read the question title. It clearly states "command prompt", which is the same as "command line"